# unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str' with numpy arange

Tags: python, numpy

My code is below and I am getting the following error:

```
X_grid = np.arange(min(X), max(X), 0.1)  
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

Comment: `X` is a `str`? If yes, you might want to add `X = float(X)` before you use it in calculations.

Comment: Welcome to SO; this is an issue with Numpy `arange` and `min`/`max`, and has nothing to do with polynomial regression, or `machine-learning`. Also, any code that comes *after* the error is irrelevant (never executed), and should not be included here (edited).

Comment: Most probably your `X` i a string, hence any `min` if `max` operations are not supported. You should convert them to numbers.

Comment: X is the dataset